# Convert entered date into UTC in JavaScript based on browser location

Tags: javascript, utc, datetime-format

My app will be run in Mexico and Australia.

When a user selects a date I format it as; "Friday 17 August 2012"

Now, how do I convert that string value into a UTC date?

So far I have this;

```
var enteredDate = $('.CreateDateRange').val() + " 07:00:00";
var thisDate = new Date(enteredDate);
var utcDate = new Date(thisDate.getUTCFullYear(), thisDate.getUTCMonth(), thisDate.getUTCDay(), thisDate.getUTCHours(), 0, 0);
```

But on the above date the returned date is; 2012 7 4 21:0:0 which is not correct.

From Australia I expect the UTC date to be something like "2012 8 17" or "2012 8 16" depending on time of day.

Comment: Did you try `toUTCString` ? Please try `enteredDate.toString()` and `enteredDate.toUTCString()` and check the timezone offsets. See the edited answer.

Comment: Don't use the browser location; just follow its time zone. Someone's computer might be set to his home time zone when traveling.

Answer (score 1):

Find the UTC specific methods in Date object

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

[getUTCDate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDate), 
[getUTCDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCDay), 
[getUTCFullYear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCFullYear), 
[getUTCHours](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCHours), 
[getUTCMilliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMilliseconds), 
[getUTCMinutes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMinutes), 
[getUTCMonth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCMonth), 
[getUTCSeconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getUTCSeconds), 
[toUTCString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString)

EDIT:

toUTCString will give you what you need

```
var enteredDate = $('.CreateDateRange').val() + " 07:00:00";
var thisDate = new Date(enteredDate);
console.log(thisDate.toUTCString());
```